# org-mode dates in other Emacs modes

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to insert dates in an emacs buffer like I do in org-mode (`C-c .`), while in a mode other than org. Is there a minor mode for this? Calendar does not do what I need, since I can "+1" a day, for instance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a minor mode, but you can do this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c .") 'org-time-stamp)
```

Or define the key in whatever mode/keymap you want.  Note, this keybinding might conflict with key bindings in other modes.  Key bindings reserved for users are <kbd>C-c x</kbd> (where `x` [is any lower or upper case letter](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keymaps.html#Keymaps)).

Comment: don't forget to `(require 'org)` first though

Comment: I love emacs. Thank you for this.